# My selected time from time picker is not set on TextEditingController?

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, dart, timepicker

I use time picker. When I select time it selects but not display on the text-editing controller

```
Future _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    var picked = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
      initialTime: selectTime,
     );
    setState(() {
      selectTime = picked;
      print('selectTime:$picked');
      _timecontroller.value = TextEditingValue(text: picked.toString());
    });
  }
```

Comment: isnt it _timecontroller.text = picked.toString() ?

Comment: @Marc I use this also but not set

Comment: can you show more code. where the controller is defined and where the text field is?

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following two options will work for you.

```
_timecontroller.value = TextEditingValue(text: selectTime.format(context).trim());
```

or

```
_timecontroller.value = TextEditingValue(text: selectTime.hour.toString()+":"+selectTime.minute.toString()));
```